# How to use ManyToManyField with condition

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

In django models I need to filtering ManyToManyField
with some condition

```py
STATUS_CHOICES=(
  ('ACTIVE', 'Active'),
  ('INACTIVE', 'Inactive'),)
  

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='ACTIVE')

class Showroom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    stock_car = models.ManyToManyField('Car')
```

This code is my attempt to get a list of all cars but I need to filter based on some condition.

I need `ManyToManyField` to contain only a car marked by

> status = 'ACTIVE'

Any idea how to handle it or some sample code is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want that on the admin interface?

Comment: Yes, I want this on admin interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ModelAdmin you can use the formfield_for_manytomany to filter your data
You can see more details in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany)

i.e:

```
class ShowroomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "stock_car":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Car.objects.filter(status='ACTIVE')
        return super(ShowroomAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you wish to obtain all show rooms with active cars:

```
Showroom.objects.filter(stock_car__status='ACTIVE')
```

More information: [Django documentation: Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: correct answer for use in views, but I need to filter in models that shown in select list in cms.

Comment: Which cms? You should include all details in your question.